# Java Import Library - JSP (netbeans)

Tags: jsp, netbeans, twitter4j

If only it was as easy as the title suggests.

The problem is:

- I am using JSP on a glassfish server.
- I am trying to import twitter4j library.

This is the first part of the problem. So I guess it's best to start here. I have tried to add the jar library (twitter4j-core-2.2.1-sources.jar) but when I try calling twitter4j... i just get it does not exist. I can see the "twitter4j-core-2.2.1-sources.jar" under "libraries" in netbeans.

I can not see where I am going wrong. I have tried some of the examples but they can not find the package so I must be including it into netbeans incorrectly.

**Part 2:**

Also the fact I am trying to do this in a web application how do I use the classes in JSP? (bonus points to anyone that helps here):

> java class and: import twitter4j.*; ?
>
> Class.forName("twitter4j.conf.CongigurationBuilder").newInstance();
>   ?
>
> <%@page import="twitter4j"%> ?

etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get all your JARs into a WAR that's deployed on Glassfish.  All JARs belong in your WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory in order for the Glassfish class loader to find them.

You should know how to create and deploy a WAR by hand.  I'd recommend doing that to make sure it works, then go back into the IDE and figure out how to make it do what you did on your own.

The right way to get those classes into your JSP is:

```
<%@page import="twitter4j"%>
```

I'm not sure that Twitter code belongs in JSPs.  Scriptlets certainly don't.  You should be using JSTL.

Comment: dare I confess, I have been coding jsp like you would script php. It has been working as required so far but I know there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the JAR file of the library in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp. You need to create a normal Java class which does the desired job using this library. You need to create a servlet class which imports/uses this class, stores the results -if any- in request scope, forwards the request to a JSP which in turn displays the results in HTML markup. Finally let the browser URL point to the URL of the servlet.

I'd suggest to learn JSP/Servlet first (assuming that you already know basic Java). Then you can apply the things learnt on whatever you'd like to achieve with Twitter4j. Start at [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).